# Python: Lambda Function to Return Values Based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to apply a lambda function to a DataFrame where I check multiple conditions.

The relevant columns in the DataFrame:

| shooter_id | shot_made | player_id_1 | total_points | free_throw_id | free_throw_made | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | 42 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1 |
| 42 | True | 42 | 2 | NaN | NaN | 2 |
| 30 | True | 42 | 2 | NaN | NaN | 3 |
| NaN | NaN | 42 | NaN | 42 | True | 3 |
| NaN | NaN | 42 | NaN | 42 | False | 4 |
| 42 | True | 42 | 5 | NaN | NaN | 5 |

I want to add a column to the DataFrame that has the most recent total_points values, while also adding 1 to the rows where the free_throw_made = True, as the total_points does not reflect these...

| shooter_id | shot_made | player_id_1 | total_points | free_throw_id | free_throw_made | time | player_id_1_total_points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | 42 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1 | 0 |
| 42 | True | 42 | 2 | NaN | NaN | 2 | 2 |
| 30 | True | 42 | 2 | NaN | NaN | 3 | 2 |
| NaN | NaN | 42 | NaN | 42 | True | 3 | 3 |
| NaN | NaN | 42 | NaN | 42 | False | 4 | 3 |
| 42 | True | 42 | 5 | NaN | NaN | 5 | 5 |

I've tried a few different bits of code, but I can't work out the proper logic or syntax.

For example, I ran this:

```py
def points(x):
    if x == df['shooter_id'] & df['shot_made']:
        return df['total_points']
    elif x == df['free_throw_id'] & df['free_throw_made']:
        df['total_points'] += 1 
    else:
        return df['total_points']

df['player_id_1_total_points'] = df['player_id_1'].apply(lambda x: points(x))
```

Not only did this return an error (unsupported operand types float and bool), as I'm writing this I'm also realizing it would not return the most recent total_points value...

Any guidance would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: As an aside, a lambda is just an anonymous function. Its okay to use a named function instead. `lambda x: points(x)` could be replaced with `points`. You have an anonymous function but all it does is call a named function with the same parameter and returns its results. It just wastes time.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the helpful comment!

Answer (score 1):

First group the dataframe by `player_id_1` then for each group forward fill the values in `total_points` then add with `free_throw_made`, finally take the cumulative max to calculate most recent total points:

```
def func(g):
    return (
        g['total_points'].ffill()
        .add(g['free_throw_made'], fill_value=0)
        .fillna(0).cummax().to_frame()
    )


df['player_id_1_total_points'] = df.groupby('player_id_1').apply(func)
```

Result

```
   shooter_id shot_made  player_id_1  total_points  free_throw_id free_throw_made  time  player_id_1_total_points
0         NaN       NaN           42           NaN            NaN             NaN     1                       0.0
1        42.0      True           42           2.0            NaN             NaN     2                       2.0
2        30.0      True           42           2.0            NaN             NaN     3                       2.0
3         NaN       NaN           42           NaN           42.0            True     3                       3.0
4         NaN       NaN           42           NaN           42.0           False     4                       3.0
5        42.0      True           42           5.0            NaN             NaN     5                       5.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time... this worked like a charm and was exactly what I needed. I'm self-taught and still have a lot to learn, and it blows me away that strangers are so quick to help out on this site. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a function, you can directly use vectorial code:

```
g = df.assign(free_throw_made=df['free_throw_made'].eq(True)).groupby('player_id_1')
df['player_id_1_total_points'] = (g['total_points'].ffill().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
                                  +g['free_throw_made'].cumsum()
                                 )
```

output:

```
   shooter_id shot_made  player_id_1  total_points  free_throw_id  \
0         NaN       NaN           42           NaN            NaN   
1        42.0      True           42           2.0            NaN   
2        30.0      True           42           2.0            NaN   
3         NaN       NaN           42           NaN           42.0   
4         NaN       NaN           42           NaN           42.0   
5        42.0      True           42           5.0            NaN   

  free_throw_made  time  player_id_1_total_points  
0             NaN     1                         0  
1             NaN     2                         2  
2             NaN     3                         2  
3            True     3                         3  
4           False     4                         3  
5             NaN     5                         6
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help, this also worked really well - really appreciate it